# get any day of the week from nsdate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone NSDate eg. next Friday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886252/iphone-nsdate-eg-next-friday)

I have one date assume today's date and now i want that all the array of week day of corresponding date or monday and saturday of corresponding week how can I do that?
-Thanx

Comment: jst got the solution from this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886252/iphone-nsdate-eg-next-friday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
NSMutableArray *weekdays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; 
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
for (int i=1; i <= 7 ;i++) 
{

    [weekdays addObject:[today dateByAddingTimeInterval:((i-[comp weekday])*24*60*60)]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",weekdays);
NSLog(@"Monday :%@ StaturDay:%@",[weekdays objectAtIndex:1],[weekdays objectAtIndex:6]);
```

Comment: thanx a lot superb solution.........

Answer (score 1):

I was using following code. Try this

```
NSMutableArray *daysArray;
        NSString *weekdayStr;
        NSMutableArray *weekdayArray;

weekdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    daysArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

        NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:currentDate];

    int month ;
    int year ;
    //int weekDay ;
    int day ;

    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit |NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;   
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
        day = [weekdayComponents day]-i;
        month = [weekdayComponents month];
        year = [weekdayComponents year];
    //  weekDay = [weekdayComponents weekday]-i;

        NSDateComponents *compsTime = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        [compsTime setDay:day];
        [compsTime setMonth:month];
        [compsTime setYear:year];

        NSString *tempString = [inputFormatter stringFromDate:[gregorian dateFromComponents:compsTime]];
        NSArray *separateString=[tempString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *date=[separateString objectAtIndex:0];

        [daysArray addObject:date];

        NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents1 = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[gregorian dateFromComponents:compsTime]];
        int weekDay1 = [weekdayComponents1 weekday];

        switch (weekDay1) {
            case 1:
                weekdayStr = @"(Sunday)";
                break;
            case 2:
                weekdayStr = @"(Monday)";
                break;
            case 3:
                weekdayStr = @"(Tuesday)";
                break;
            case 4:
                weekdayStr = @"(Wednesday)";
                break;

            case 5:
                weekdayStr = @"(Thursday)";
                break;

            case 6:
                weekdayStr = @"(Friday)";
                break;

            case 7:
                weekdayStr = @"(Saturday)";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        NSLog(@"weekDay %@ date: %@",weekdayStr,tempString);
         [weekdayArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",weekDay1]];
    }
    NSLog(@"days array: %@", weekdayArray)
```

Comment: thanx but it will give me next seven days i want current week days btw  vignesh sol works